# Expo project not starting

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

My expo project doesn't start when I try to use npm start.
Versions that I am using are

Expo-cli: 3.20.5

Node : 12.16.3

Flow:

expo init project

-> blank template

expo start

After running the expo start command it gives the following error

```
Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.
ConfigError: Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.
    at Object.getExpoSDKVersion (C:\Users\Talha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\config\src\Project.ts:35:9)
    at ensureConfigHasDefaultValues (C:\Users\Talha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\config\src\Config.ts:419:22)
    at fillAndReturnConfig (C:\Users\Talha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\config\src\Config.ts:101:10)
    at configureProjectAsync (C:\Users\Talha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:281:25)
    at action (C:\Users\Talha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:157:34)
    at C:\Users\Talha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:334:16
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Talha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:85:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

Then as mentioned in the above first line I ran  npm install expo

After running the command for installing expo it gives me the following error

```
Error: React Native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your project directory.
Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project.
    at startExpoServerAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@57.9.5\src\Project.ts:2080:11)
    at Object.startAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@57.9.5\src\Project.ts:2397:5)
    at action (C:\Users\Talha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:170:3)
    at C:\Users\Talha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:341:16
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Talha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:85:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
```

Then I ran npm install mentioned in the above error but then got this error

```
npm WARN deprecated deep-assign@3.0.0: Check out `lodash.merge` or `merge-options` instead.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file
```

after that when i again try to npm start it keeps repeating itself through the same errors I mentioned above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that npm install is not working on your machine, possibly due to some cache issues. you can run `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm install` again to try to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Ya8.png) I had the same issue and cleaned up my node module. But the issue came back because I kill my server the wrong way. So I **cleaned the repo** again and close my server properly. And now I **all the time close correctly my server**. The issue didn't happen again for the moment.

=> Don't kill your cmd, you have to close the server correctly by doing `CMD+C` for win 10.